# Utiliza paramentos existentes em um parentNode de segundo nível

Tags: javascript, objetos

Tenho o seguinte objeto como exemplo:

```
var teste = {
    config : {
         dir: "myDir",
         type:"myType"
    },
    fn : {
         foo : function(){
             console.log(this); //retorna o objeto fn
         },
         bar : function(){
             console.log(this[1].config.dir); // entendo que fn seria this[0]
             console.log(this.this.config.dir); //deveria retornar teste
             console.log(this..config.dir); //não funciona por não ter parametro
         }
    }
}
```

Preciso saber se há alguma forma de acessar o meu objeto que está em um segundo `parentNode` para então entrar no objeto `config` e pegar o valor do parâmetro `dir`.

Hoje eu sou obrigado a chamar meu próprio objeto quando me encontro em uma situação semelhante. Há alguma forma de chamar um parente que esteja em nós níveis maiores do que o nó do parâmetro?

Answer (score 1):

Eu entendo que você deveria definir uma classe pra fazer o serviço:

```
function MyClass(config) {
    this.dir = config.dir;
    this.type = config.type;
}

MyClass.prototype.foo = function (){
    console.log(this);
}

MyClass.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log(this.dir);
}

var myObject = new MyClass({
    dir: "myDir",
    type: "myType",
});

myObject.foo();
myObject.bar();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkx63gr2/).

Eu acho que você está confundindo os conceitos — essas coisas tipo `parentNode` só existem para elementos do DOM, i.e. pedacinhos da página. Se você definir seus próprios objetos, você tem que criar quaisquer referências a pais e filhos que você queira usar à mão.